# Try Catch in .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, error-handling, try-catch

I was searching the most effective and elegant way do to the follows:

- My function can be called while Filename is valid, corrupted, not exist

The function will just deserialize an XML object.

The main possible results are:

- OK
- File doesn't exist
- Error in XML file

If I write this way, the reader won't be closed in case of corrupted file.
IF I write the reader.close() inside finally block, It gaves me a warning about using read before assigning it a value.

So, how can I solve this inside the sub??

```
Public Function DeSerializzaXML(ByVal FileName As String, ByRef tmpObj As Object, ByVal tmpClass As Type) As Boolean
    Dim serializer As XmlSerializer
    Dim reader As StreamReader
    Dim tmpSuccess As Boolean = False
    Try
        serializer = New XmlSerializer(tmpClass)
        reader = New StreamReader(FileName)
        tmpObj = serializer.Deserialize(reader)
        reader.Close()
        tmpSuccess = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        AggiungiRigaSuFile(ErroriPath, FileName + ", " + ex.Message, Configurazione.DiagnosticaOff, True)
    Finally

    End Try

    Return tmpSuccess
End Function
```

Comment: Please try to write English code (variables and method names). I am Italian and understand but this is an international site. :)

Comment: I'm not sure that variable names and methods matter that much. Certainly it caused me no problems and I couldn't even have told you that the language was italian.

Comment: I'm sorry, i did not translate var and fun name cause i supposed it's not the focus of the deal!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just initialize the reader with `Nothing` and only dispose it in the finally block if it is not `Nothing`:

```
Dim reader As StreamReader = Nothing
Try
    ...
Finally

    If reader IsNot Nothing Then

        reader.Dispose();

    End If

End Try
```

As I seldom do VB.NET, I am not exactly sure about the syntax, please fix any errors yourself. The idea of the code should be clear.

Comment: good practice in general. OR write more than one try/catch block if the exceptions are too different.

Comment: I don't get your second part about multiple try/catch blocks. You can have multiple catch blocks for one try and one finally block: `try { } catch(InvalidOperationException e1) { } catch(ArgumentNullException e2) { } finally { }`

Comment: Is this better than just using a `using` statement which is designed for this kind of thing? It seems like a more wordy alternative to me...

Comment: @Chris: It depends. Sometimes this is the way to go, especially if working with StreamReaders, because they already dispose the underlying stream. See [this explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx) for more info. But in this particular case, a `Using` would probably be more appropriate, you are right.

Comment: @daniel that's exactly what I meant. people tend to write a big try/catch block catching the root Exception...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Thanks. I'd not come across that one before. Its a very interesting point. Its a shame really that there is no way to guarantee that disposing things multiple times is safe but I can't imagine any way you could enforce that guarantee. :)

Comment: @Chris According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx): _"If an object's Dispose method is called more than once, the object must ignore all calls after the first one."_. So, while it is technically true that the second call to Dispose cannot be guaranteed to be safe, if it isn't, then this is a bug in Dispose, not in the code that uses it.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: The comment was in reference to the link that Daniel posted that says "A correctly implemented Dispose method can be called multiple times without throwing an exception. However, this is not guaranteed and to avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call Dispose more than one time on an object."

Comment: @Chris I understand, I was just making a point that fixing root cause of the bug should be preferred over fixing the symptoms.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: Ah, cool. In that case I totally agree. :-)

Answer (score 5):

try using a 'using' statement in the reader initialisation. if it's disposable, then when the Dispose method is called, the reader will be closed automatically

[more from microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)

as an alternative, you can use multiple catch statements on different exception types.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if it has a value before accessing it.

```
If reader IsNot Nothing Then ...
```

Better still, use a `Using` block, then you won't have to worry in the finally.

```
Using reader = New StreamReader(FileName)
    ...
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you explicitly check to see if the file exists rather than relying on an exception being thrown, it’s more efficient and it allows you to report a more accurate error message.

```
 If(File.Exists(curFile)) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reader = New StreamReader(FileName)
Try
   ...
Finally
   reader.Dispose()
End Try
```

Or just use [Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: this will raise exception - File not exist if you do reader outside try!

Comment: @RiccardoNeri Which is exactly what you want - you don't want to call `Dispose` on a `null`. If you want to handle the exception, wrap it in another Try.

Answer (score 0):

with regards to try catch, you should be catching specific exceptions

```
Catch ex As XmlException
```

or

```
Catch ex As IOException
```

you could try and eliminate the IO exception by checking if file exists and is accessible (exception could still be raised, but it's better to avoid it).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
if io.file.exist(filename) then
    return io.file.readallbytes(filename)
end if
```

Comment: Any chance you could explain this a bit, and why it's an answer to the question?